# SQL Server JOIN - displaying two joined values in one query that map to one other table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is an example of the data set I am working with. I am trying to write a query that will allow me to request a row from the items table, and display the User Name from the users table in place of the user ids:

```
Table 1 - users table

User ID | User Name 
--------------------
12      | Fred
13      | Ted
14      | Ned

Table 2 - items Table

Item ID | Submitted User | Assigned User
----------------------------------------
234     | 12             | 14
345     | 12             | 13
456     | 14             | 12
```

This is as far as I can get, which returns one properly labled username:

```
SELECT users.[user name] AS [Submitted User] FROM items 
JOIN users ON items.[Assigned User] = users.[User ID]
WHERE items.[Item ID] = '234'
```

The problem with this is that while ONE field works, I need to get both the submitted user AND the assigned user. I am trying to do it in one query... I have a feeling it can be done but I just don't know exactly how. If I try to assign the fields more than once I get an error about correlation. Here is an example of what I tried that gives a correlation error:

```
SELECT users.[user name] AS [Submitted User], users.[user name] AS [Assigned User] FROM items 
JOIN users ON items.[Submitted User] = users.[User ID]
JOIN users ON items.[Assigned User] = users.[User ID]
WHERE items.[Item ID] = '234'
```

This is exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT 
  items[Submitted User].users.[user name] AS [Reported User],
  items[Assigned User].users.[user name] AS [Assigned User] 
WHERE items.[Item ID] = '234'</pre>
```

This is the response I'm trying to get:

```
Submitted User | Assigned user
Fred           - Ted
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to alias your JOIN table so that you can join against it twice.  See below:

```
SELECT 
    submitted.[user name] AS [Submitted User], 
    assigned.[user name] AS [Assigned User] 
FROM items 
    LEFT JOIN users submitted ON items.[Submitted User] = submitted.[User ID]
    LEFT JOIN users assigned ON items.[Assigned User] = assigned.[User ID]
WHERE items.[Item ID] = '234'
```

Some other suggestions:

- Table 2's column names should be Submitted User ID, Assigned User ID to make it more explicit that you're joining IDs.
- You might want to make your ID fields INT.  It makes for faster joins and less space.
- Don't forget to build indices on the ID fields on both tables so the JOIN can take advantage of them.
- Thanks astander, changed join to LEFT JOIN since you probably want to see the results

Comment: Works great, thank you very much! It took me a few tries to convert this to my database tables and values... but after doing that I think I have a better idea of what it's doing. Thanks again!